# AWS regional service availability

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Working on development of a cloud-based app using AWS CDK using the TS template and I'd like to be able to check for a service's availability in a region and handle the case that it's not available, ideally deploy to another region with the availability for a particular service.

I've got an idea on how to check but it seems sub-optimal and a little hack-y.

```
$ curl --request GET \
  --url https://pinpoint.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/


$ curl --request GET \
  --url https://pinpoint.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to use some function like [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/region-selection.html#region-selection-query-service), but I can't seem to find one in the JS AWS SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly, there are no methods for that in the other language versions of the SDK. However, I found something called [AWS Systems Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/what-is-systems-manager.html) that might be exactly what we need. (By the way, [these](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#view-service-endpoints) are the declared ways of accessing AWS endpoints and services information).

AWS SSM has a feature called [Parameter Store's Public Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/parameter-store-public-parameters.html). Some information about AWS endpoints and services can be accessed through them.

- [AWS SSM API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html)
- [AWS JavaScript SDK SSM Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SSM.html)
- [Actions Examples](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-query-for-aws-regions-endpoints-and-more-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/)

Some useful actions could be:

- `getParameter`
- `getParameters`
- `getParametersByPath`
- `describeParameters`

Consider that you may need to be authenticated to perform some actions.

I didn't really have the time to test it thoroughly, so please let me know if somehow it helps solving your problem.